# How to remove the RSS feed icon form the content listing pages?

Tags: 7

I need to remove the syndication icon because I'm either not going to syndicate or I want to do it my own way.

Answer (score 7):

If it's just the feed icon you need to kill, you could always just comment out or delete the line:

```
<?php print $feed_icons; ?>
```

from page.tpl.php?

Answer (score 2):

If you have Omega theme comment out this line

```
<?php if ($feed_icons): ?><div class="feed-icon clearfix"><?php print $feed_icons; ?></div><?php endif; ?>
```

It is in region--content.tpl.php

Answer (score 2):

better bet is to use David Norman's (deekayan) [Jammer](https://drupal.org/project/jammer) module.

Install it and then enable the following module's:

1. Feed Icon Jammer
2. Feed Jammer

the first, of course, removes the icon, and  the second prevents the front page from being published as an RSS feed.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

See [Port to Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/945462); a Drupal 7 version of RSS permissions is in the works and may already have some of the functionalities you require.

Answer (score 0):

As [marblegravy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/4706/12010) correctly suggest you should indeed remove the link from your theme. This is different for each theme, but for example in Bartik you can remove the following line in page.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $feed_icons; ?>
```

Just search for *RSS* or *feed* and you should find the link.

Additionally to prevent some smart crawler from accessing the feed, you can block access to it by implementing [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) in a custom module. E.g. as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYCUSTOMMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['rss.xml']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

For more fine grained control I recommend the module [RSS permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/rss_permissions)