# Remove RSS feed icon and create custom RSS feed

Tags: 7, feeds

1. I want to disable the default Drupal 7 RSS feeds located at /rss.xml.
   Can this be achieved?
2. I want to create my own custom RSS feeds.
   I have tried with the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module, but I can't define my own fields, and default feed contains a lot of HTML etc. I just want to create a clean RSS feed with title and body summarized to 150 chars, but without HTML, like in this feed: b.dk/seneste/rss.

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily have to disable rss.xml. You really want to change the default feed on the page. That can be done with theming; change `<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="" href="rss.xml" />` to whatever you want it to be

Comment: For question 1: see the answers in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-to-remove-the-feed-icon-form-the-content-listing-pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, I found the [RSS Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/rss_permissions) module, which allow you to disable the RSS feeds based on roles. I haven't tested this out, but it seems to be actively developed. (NOTE: This is for Drupal 7.)

Comment: Yes it defiantly looks like RSS Permissions module can fix my issue for question 1.

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, I have used the answer by Rick Umali.

For question 2:
I made a field formatter for the text fields called "Trimmed and stripped" that first strips all HTML and then trims the length of the value.
Next I configured the RSS display type for my content types to use this "Trimmed and stripped" field formatter on body.
Finally I created the wanted views through Views 3.x module.

But this still leaves HTML around each field. And I wanted to have a clean RSS feed, so I also created a template file named views-view-row-rss.tpl.php, which runs a htmlspecialchars_decode() on $description, and then strip_tags() and finally check_plain()...

And I now got the wanted result - but I think there most be a better solution out there...
Or else I should maybe write a module for this one day :)

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: You should use Views module to create a feed on that path, this will override the items included in the home page feed.

Question 2: You can change the default RSS settings for the site to include full node content or the title or title + summary. Then on a per content type you can set a custom display for feeds, if you need to tweak what is included in the feeds.